# What level do you have to be to get infinity on your bow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been wondering for a while what level do you have to be to get infinity on your bow?

Comment: A search through http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Enchanting lead me to [this](http://pernsteiner.org/minecraft/enchant/tables/Infinity_1.html) page, that seems to indicate that the bare minimum to enchant a Bow with Infinity is Level 21. I would write this as an answer, if my knowledge on Minecraft wasn't terribly outdated.

Answer (score 13):

[Minecraft Enchantment Calculator](http://minecraftenchantmentcalculator.com/rev5/) looks pretty good and definitely gives the right idea of the shape of the distrubution. I feel I can add just a little bit more insight. I have ran the actual game code that creates the enchantments 1,000,000 times per level and counted how many times I got any enchantment at each level. Here are the [raw results](http://pastebin.com/uAQ3ittk) and here is the chart with selected a few enchantments:
[image: higher level some bow enchantments]
You'll notice some small differences in results compared with Minecraft Enchantment Calculator (besides the lines being a bit smoother because of the greater number of simulations):

- The Infinity enchantment probability rises steadily with level (although the slope is small), as opposed to staying flat
- The probability value is 10-14%, as opposed to 6%

The results are a bit different because Minecraft Enchantment Calculator is reimplementation of the enchantment algorithm in javascript and as such it is not perfect, while the simulations shown here invoke the actual game code to get the enchantments. Still, Minecraft Enchantment Calculator is really easy to use and gives a good enough idea of the shape of the probability.

Comment: You should really make a website with that simulator... That's awesome. :)

Answer (score 6):

Using the website [Minecraft Enchanting Calculator](http://minecraftenchantmentcalculator.com/rev5/) (Minecraft version 1.7+) -

Possible levels for an Infinity I bow...

**Level 17**: 0.5%

**Level 18**: 2%

**Level 19**: 3.6%

**Level 20**: 5.3%

**Level 21**: 5.5%

**Level 22**: 5.5%

**Level 23**: 6%

**Level 24**: 5.8%

**Level 25**: 5.8%

**Level 26**: 5.9%

**Level 27**: 5.7%

**Level 28**: 5.6%

**Level 29**: 5.7%

**Level 30**: 6.1%

[image: graph showing spread of infinity across levels]

The website simulates enchantments 10,000 times and outputs the results (but results may still vary)

Comment: Using this data, and assuming an endless supply of unenchanted bows, the best level for Infinity is 20, since you have a 0.265% chance of Infinity per level.

Comment: For anyone searching: The site is offline, but you can find working versions from earlier years at archive.org. The site is fully client-based, so it's not a problem that the actual server is offline.